# Creating a Group from another Group and Automorphism of that group?

Tags: group-theory

[image]Suppose $G$ is a group and $T$ is an automorphism of $G$ of order $k$. We create a group $\{G,T\}$ (Construction given in Herstein 2nd edition Pg 69). Now in the explanation given in text, it specifically mentioned that $T$ should **not be** an inner automorphism but didn't give a reason. I deduced that this would imply $'g'$ belongs to G will have order which divides $r$ which is not necessarily true ( for example take $\mathbb{Z}_9$, its set of automorphisms is isomorphic to multiplication group $U(9)$; $(8,1)$ is a subgroup of it which corresponds to some $T$ whose order is $2$ but no element of $G$ can have order $2$, hence my point).

So is the real purpose of not choosing such a $T$ is same as mine? If yes then what prevents me from choosing some other $S$ from inner automorphisms where their is indeed an element $'g'$ of order that divides $r$, or is the author playing safe?

Comment: While I'm sure many people have a copy of Herstein, the question is not very self-contained: It's essentially unintelligible without the book. It would be best to explain what $\{G,T\}$ is and other necessary details.

Comment: @pjs36 I have added the photo in case someone doesn't have the book. The para above eg 2.8.1 is relevant.